# Replace string with symbol using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vue.js

I have this text `@abc some text here`. How can I make it into `<a href="some_url">@abc</a> some text here` using javascript? any library to do that?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here. Are you after a regex replace? Where is "some text here" coming from?

Comment: @Shadow any alternative beside regex?

Comment: There are always other ways. But, as I said, you haven't made it clear what it is you are actually trying to do. Maybe consider adding some more examples of "before" and "after", and also have a go at writing the transformation yourself. Then what you're trying to do will be much clearer.

Comment: answer below answered it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex replacement:

```js
var input = "@abc some text here";
var output = input.replace(/(@\S+)/, "<a href=\"some_url\">$1</a>");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: what if you have double @? just put `/g`?

Comment: @JenniferAlexis Yes...but what if the replacements are different?  If the replacements are the same, the `/g` should be fine.

Comment: you're right, what if the replacement is different? says the url is array, use a loop to replace?

Comment: The basic `replace` API doesn't support that, its interface is find many replace once.